# Derivation of Richardson Extrapolation update rule for arbitrary $k$

Tags: numerical-methods

In the Wikipedia article on [Richardson Extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation#), a recursive formula is shown:

$$
A_{i + 1}(h) = \frac{t^{k^i}A_i(h/t) + A_i(h)}{t^{k^i} - 1}
$$

I'm finding this hard to generalize into an algorithm that accepts an estimator function because of the $k^i$ bit, which I have interpreted as the order of the error for the base estimator. I've noticed that some approximations have error terms that are consecutive integer powers, some which are even powers, and some which are odd powers.

So, if I'm writing an algorithm to do this for me, It seems like I would need to know the approximation error term powers for the particular estimator apriori. Is there a way to derive a formula that is agnostic to the estimator's error term pattern?

Comment: @Carl Christian I have not read the answer yet. I'll read it on Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the target value and let $A_h$ denote our approximation. If there exists an asymptotic error expansion of the form
$$T - A_h = \alpha h^p + \beta h^q + O(h^r), \quad h \rightarrow 0_+,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants independent of $h$ and the exponents $$0<p<q<r$$ are not necessarily integers, then the following is true:

1. We have $$\alpha h^p = \frac{A_h - A_{2h}}{2^p - 1} + O(h^q), \quad h \rightarrow 0_+.$$
2. If we define $$F_h = \frac{A_{2h} - A_{4h}}{A_h - A_{2h}},$$ then $$F_h \rightarrow 2^p, \quad h \rightarrow 0_+$$
3. Moreover, there is a constant $c$ such that $$\frac{F_h - 2^p}{h^n} \rightarrow c, \quad h \rightarrow 0_+,$$ where $n=q-p$.

Item 1 contains Richardson's error estimate. Item 2 and 3 concerns Richardson's fraction $F_h$. By monitoring the computed values of Richardson's fraction you can determine the value of $p$ and identify the asymptotic range, i.e., the set of values of $h$ where rounding errors are insignificant compared with the discretization error. Item 3 show that you can determine the difference between the order of the primary error term $\alpha h^p$ and the secondary error term $\beta h^q$ by observing the valus of $F_h - 2^p$.

To be fair, these observations are hard to turn into software which automatically detects the values of $p$ and $q$. It is essentially impossible to distinguish between say $p=2$ and $p=2.001$. It is important to realize we don't need the exact value of $p$ to get a good approximation of Richardson error estimate. We need a good approximation of $2^p-1$. The asymptotic range is characterized by $$\log(|F_h - 2^p|) \approx \log|c| + n \log(h).$$

As an example of what is possible for a human we consider the problem of computing the integral $$T = \int_0^1 e^x dx = e^1 - 1.$$ We choose the composite trapezoidal rule as our approximation $A_h$. It is known that $p=2$ and $q=4$ for this rule, but we shall verify this experimentally. We have the following data:

> ```
>  k |    Approximation A_h | Fraction F_h |   Error estimate E_h |                Error |   Comparison
>  0 |   1.859140914230e+00 |   0.00000000 |   0.000000000000e+00 |  -1.408590857705e-01 |   0.0000e+00
>  1 |   1.753931092465e+00 |   0.00000000 |  -3.506994058823e-02 |  -3.564926400578e-02 |  -1.7891e+00
>  2 |   1.727221904558e+00 |   3.93908726 |  -8.903062635770e-03 |  -8.940076098471e-03 |  -2.3830e+00
>  3 |   1.720518592164e+00 |   3.98447608 |  -2.234437464405e-03 |  -2.236763705256e-03 |  -2.9830e+00
>  4 |   1.718841128580e+00 |   3.99610010 |  -5.591545281024e-04 |  -5.593001209490e-04 |  -3.5845e+00
>  5 |   1.718421660316e+00 |   3.99902383 |  -1.398227545558e-04 |  -1.398318572816e-04 |  -4.1864e+00
>  6 |   1.718316786850e+00 |   3.99975588 |  -3.495782207789e-05 |  -3.495839104795e-05 |  -4.7885e+00
>  7 |   1.718290568083e+00 |   3.99993897 |  -8.739588871635e-06 |  -8.739624433041e-06 |  -5.3905e+00
>  8 |   1.718284013367e+00 |   3.99998474 |  -2.184905553001e-06 |  -2.184907774039e-06 |  -5.9929e+00
>  9 |   1.718282374686e+00 |   3.99999619 |  -5.462269084452e-07 |  -5.462270487033e-07 |  -6.5904e+00
> 10 |   1.718281965016e+00 |   3.99999904 |  -1.365567600479e-07 |  -1.365567685596e-07 |  -7.2053e+00
> 11 |   1.718281862598e+00 |   3.99999982 |  -3.413919154778e-08 |  -3.413919391626e-08 |  -7.1588e+00
> 12 |   1.718281836994e+00 |   3.99999982 |  -8.534798275524e-09 |  -8.534799089688e-09 |  -7.0205e+00
> 13 |   1.718281830593e+00 |   3.99999566 |  -2.133701881846e-09 |  -2.133693444151e-09 |  -5.4029e+00
> 14 |   1.718281828992e+00 |   3.99999681 |  -5.334258960469e-10 |  -5.334157560100e-10 |  -4.7210e+00
> 15 |   1.718281828592e+00 |   4.00004551 |  -1.333549567069e-10 |  -1.333508858892e-10 |  -4.5153e+00
> 16 |   1.718281828492e+00 |   4.00022202 |  -3.333688880502e-11 |  -3.334021947410e-11 |  -4.0004e+00
> 17 |   1.718281828467e+00 |   4.00046186 |  -8.333260007968e-12 |  -8.340439450194e-12 |  -3.0651e+00
> 18 |   1.718281828461e+00 |   3.98094194 |  -2.093288505497e-12 |  -2.060573933704e-12 |  -1.7992e+00
> 19 |   1.718281828460e+00 |   4.13782004 |  -5.058916248875e-13 |  -5.428990590417e-13 |  -1.1664e+00
> ```

The step sizes used are $h_k = 2^{-k}$. $A_h$ is the approximation, $F_h$ is Richardson's fraction (which is only defined for $k \ge 3$) $E_h$ is Richardson's error estimate (which is only defined for $k\ge 2$). The two last two columns contain the actual error and compares Richardson's error estimate to the actual error. Specifically, the actual error is treated as a target value, Richardson's error estimate as the approximation and the last column contains $\log_{10}$ of the associated relative error.

This figure shows displays the convergence of Richardson's fraction:
[image]
From the table it is reasonably clear that if $p$ is an integer, then it has to be $p=2$ because the computed values of $F_h$ (initially) appear to converge toward $4 = 2^2$. The picture reveals that the asymptotic range is $k=2,3, \dots, 10$. The slope of the straight line is $-2$, which shows that $q=p+2=4$. At $k=11$ we have reached the point where rounding errors are comparable with the discretization error and the behavior of the computed values of $F_h$ start to deviate from the behavior of the exact values of $F_h$. At this stage, there is no reason to continue. You will note that $k=10$ is also the point where the accuracy of Richardson error estimate is maximal, the relative error is about $10^{-7.2}$ which is exceedingly good.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some references that would allow me to dig deeper into how Richardson's fraction is linked to the leading error term as well as how it can be viewed as a way to analyze the asymptotic range? I don't want to ask you to expand or prove those points, but I'd like to know more. These ideas aren't mentioned in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @rocksNwaves There is J.P. Roache's textbook "Fundamentals of Verification and Validation". Roache has a number of publish papers on the subject as well. Objectively, it is a simple problem, but it there are a number of pitfalls that are visited by many. I am writing notes for my students. If you contact me directly, then I will be happy to share a draft with you.

Comment: @rocksNwaves A few misprints have been corrected.

Comment: Thank you, I will take you up on that! I've emailed the address listed on your academic profile.